# Vertical centering of all columns in \tabularx environment

Tags: tabularx, columns, vertical

I want to make a table with vertically centered columns in a `\tabularx` environment. How can I code the table to have all the column types (l, c, X) vertically centered?

Here is my code:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption[Text]{Text.}
\label{tab:5599}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|c|X|}
\hline

\textit{} & \textit{A} & \textit{B} \\
\thickhline

A & B & C
\hline

\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

EDIT:

I am still facing the problem that my text is not vertically centered:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption[Material for SDS-PAGE]{Buffer compositions for SDS-PAGE.}
\label{tab:8899}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xcccc} % way of defining a fix columns width
\toprule[1.5pt]
\textit{} & \textit{Resolving gel} & \textit{Stacking gel} & \textit{Laemmli sample buffer} & \textit{Running buffer} \\ 
\midrule[1.5pt]
Acrylamide & 10 \% & 5 \% & - & - \\
\midrule
Tris-HCl (1.5 M, pH 8.8) & 25 \% & - & - & - \\
\midrule
Tris-HCl (1.0 M, pH 6.8) & - & 12.5 \% & 6.25 \% & - \\
\midrule
SDS & 0.1 \% & 0.1 \% & - & - \\
\midrule
Ammonium persulfate & 0.1 \% & 0.1 \% & - & - \\
\midrule
TEMED & 0.04 \% & 0.1 \% & - & - \\
\midrule
2-Mercaptoethanol & - & - & 0.1 \% & - \\
\midrule
Bromophenol blue & - & - & 0.0005 \% & - \\
\midrule
Glycerol & - & - & 10 \% & - \\
\midrule
TRIS & - & - & - & 0.25 M \\
\midrule
Glycine & - & - & - & 1.92 M \\
\midrule
pH & - & - & - & 8.3 \\
\midrule
H\textsubscript{2}O & Solvent & Solvent & Solvent & Solvent \\
\bottomrule[1.5pt]
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Comment: Please make your code compilable. In my eyes, they are vertically centered. Could you show a screenshot? I do not know `\thickline` and there seems to be a \\ missing after `C`.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It seems that addition of

```
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}% for vertical centering text in X column
```

in your preamble is what you looking for:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}% for vertical centering text in X column

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}[h]
    \centering
\caption[Material for SDS-PAGE]{Buffer compositions for SDS-PAGE.}
    \label{tab:8899}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\raggedright}Xcccc} % way of defining a fix columns width
    \toprule[1.5pt]
    &   \textit{Resolving gel} 
        &   \textit{Stacking gel} 
            &   \textit{Laemmli sample buffer} 
                &   \textit{Running buffer}     \\
    \midrule[1.5pt]
Acrylamide                  & 10 \%     & 5 \%      &  --       &  --   \\
    \midrule
Tris-HCl (1.5 M, pH 8.8)    & 25 \%     &  --       &  --       &  --   \\
    \midrule
Tris-HCl (1.0 M, pH 6.8)    &  --       & 12.5 \%   & 6.25 \%   &  --   \\
    \midrule
SDS                         & 0.1 \%    & 0.1 \%    &  --       &  --   \\
    \midrule
Ammonium persulfate         & 0.1 \%    & 0.1 \%    &  --       &  --   \\
    \midrule
TEMED                       & 0.04 \%   & 0.1 \%    &  --       &  --   \\
    \midrule
2-Mercaptoethanol           &  --       &  --       & 0.1 \%    &  --   \\
    \midrule
Bromophenol blue            &  --       &  --       & 0.0005 \% &  --   \\
    \midrule
Glycerol                    &  --       &  --       & 10 \%     &  --   \\
    \midrule
TRIS                        &  --       &  --       &  --       & 0.25 M\\
    \midrule
Glycine                     &  --       &  --       &  --       & 1.92 M\\
    \midrule
pH                          &  --       &  --       &  --       & 8.3   \\
    \midrule
H\textsubscript{2}O         & Solvent   & Solvent   & Solvent   & Solvent\\
    \bottomrule[1.5pt]
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Also see, if the following solution is usable for you:

[image]

Above is used package `makecell` and its macro `thead`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs, 
            makecell, % for second example
            tabularx}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}% for vertical centering text in X column
\renewcommand\theadfont{\itshape\normalsize}% for two lines column headers 

...

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\raggedright}Xcccc} % way of defining a fix columns width
    \toprule[1.5pt]
    &   \thead{Resolving gel} 
        &   \thead{Stacking gel} 
            &   \thead{Laemmli\\ sample buffer} 
                &   \thead{Running buffer} \\
    \midrule[1.5pt]
...
```

**for fun:**

now, after 2+ years i would redesign this table as follows:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs,
            makecell, % for second example
            tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\itshape\normalsize}% for two lines column headers
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \sisetup{table-align-text-post=false,
             table-space-text-post={\,\%},
             group-four-digits}
\caption[Material for SDS-PAGE]{Buffer compositions for SDS-PAGE.}
    \label{tab:8899}
\begin{tabularx}{0.8\textwidth}{>{\raggedright}X
                                S[table-format=3.2]
                                S[table-format=3.2]
                                S[table-format=3.5]
                                l
                             }
    \toprule
    &   {\thead{Resolving\\ gel}}
        &   {\thead{Stacking\\ gel}}
            &   {\thead{Laemmli\\ sample buffer}}
                &   \thead{Running\\ buffer} \\
    \midrule
Acrylamide                  & 10 \%     & 5 \%      &  {--}     &  {--} \\
Tris-HCl (1.5 M, pH 8.8)    & 25 \%     &  {--}     &  {--}     &  {--} \\
    \addlinespace
Tris-HCl (1.0 M, pH 6.8)    &  {--}     & 12.5 \%   & 6.25 \%   &  {--} \\
SDS                         & 0.1 \%    & 0.1 \%    &  {--}     &  {--} \\
    \addlinespace
Ammonium persulfate         & 0.1 \%    & 0.1 \%    &  {--}     &  {--} \\
TEMED                       & 0.04 \%   & 0.1 \%    &  {--}     &  {--} \\
    \addlinespace
2-Mercaptoethanol           &  {--}     &  {--}     & 0.1 \%    &  {--} \\
Bromophenol blue            &  {--}     &  {--}     & 0.0005 \% &  {--} \\
    \addlinespace
Glycerol                    &  {--}     &  {--}     & 10 \%     &  {--} \\
TRIS                        &  {--}     &  {--}     &  {--}     & 0.25 M\\
    \addlinespace
Glycine                     &  {--}     &  {--}     &  {--}     & 1.92 M\\
pH                          &  {--}     &  {--}     &  {--}     & 8.3   \\
    \addlinespace
H\textsubscript{2}O         & {Solvent} & {Solvent} & {Solvent} & Solvent\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what Gernot said: you where comparing normal c and l (and to be complete r) -columns with an X-column.  The first three columntypes differ from the last one, in that LaTeX will break long text into multiple lines, if it is a X-column.  In fact, the X-column is identical to a p-column of variable width.

You'll have to keep in mind, that the text within a classical l,c or r-column is always placed with its baseline onto the surrounding baseline.  This differs from the way, the p, m and b-columns are aligned by LaTeX.  Those are also aligned to fit the surrounding baseline.  But their "inner" baseline is placed according to their identifying character.  The "p"stands for to**P**.  That is, the baseline of the top/first line of that paragraph will be aligned with the surrounding baseline.  The m-column stands for "**M**iddle" or centered alignment. The surrounding baseline will therefore pass through the middle of the vertical box height of this paragraph.  Last, but not least, the b-column, which is for "**B**ottom", will merge the baseline of its own last line with the surrounding baseline.

Lets face an example

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lp{2cm}m{2cm}b{2cm}r}
  foo & long text in the first column
  & long text in the second column
  & even longer text in the third and second-last column
  & bar
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

results in

[image]

as you can see, the words "foo" and "bar", which I've placed into the l or r-column, are perfectly aligned to the vertical middle of the middle column.

So, if you want to have the content of your l and c-columns vertically aligned to the middle of X-columns, you'll have to fiddle with LaTeX around.

You could either work with a normal tabular-environment and use a m-column declaration instead of tabularx and its X-column.  In that case, you'd have to adapt the width of your b-columns either by hand or set up a clever formulae, to have LaTeX calculate it by its own.  (Of course, you could have a glimpse on the tricks, tabularx used to do so on a p-column!)

On the other hand, you might use a clever calculated `\raisebox` to correct the position of the baseline.

Answer (score 3):

What you observe is the standard behaviour of `tabular`s in conjunction with `\hline`s. There are several solutions, like adding rules of zero width ("struts") that have an appropriate height/depth and keep the horizontal rules at the same distance. A better approach is probably to use the package `booktabs` and to avoid vertical lines (which are visually bad and unnecessary since the vertical alignment guides the reader anyway).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lcX}
\toprule
\textit{} & \textit{A} & \textit{B} \\
\midrule
A & B & C\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Adding rules with zero width is not really what I want to do. I like the other option. How can I get one of the rules (in my case '\midrule') thicker than normal rules? If I use my previously set code '\thickhline' the inital problem occurs of course again.

Comment: @MichaelEngeli The default width of top and bottom rules is `\heavyrulewidth`, for mid rules it is `\lightrulewidth`. So if you want to change the defaults completely, modify these lengths. For temporary changes use the optional parameter of the three rule commands that overrides the default; e.g., `\midrule[1pt]` produces a mid rule of width `1pt`. For more information see the [documentation of the `booktabs` package](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/booktabs.pdf).