# Vertical alignment of equation in a table cell

Tags: tables, equations

I am trying to center the equations vertically within their respective cells, but they are always aligned with the first line no matter what. This is a minimal working example of what I have so far:

```
\documentclass[titlepage, twoside, 11pt]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2.5cm]{geometry} %doc dimensions
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell} % Tabular column heads and multilined cells
\usepackage{siunitx} % (SI) units package
\sisetup{
    range-phrase=\text{--},
    range-units=single,
}
\usepackage{tabularx} %Tabulars with adjustable-width columns
\newcolumntype{a}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{b}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l a p{7cm} l}
\toprule
Parameter & Reference & Formula & Unit\\
\midrule
\makecell[lt]{Leaf water\\content (LWC)} & Author &
$\displaystyle LWC=\frac{AWT}{A}=\frac{W_f-W_d}{A}$
& \si{\kilo\gram\per\meter\squared}\\
\makecell[lt]{Equivalent water\\thickness (EWT)} & Author &
$EWT=\frac{AWT}{\rho_w \cdot A}=\frac{W_f-W_d}{\rho_w \cdot A}$
& \si{\kilo\gram\per\meter\squared}\\
\makecell[lt]{Relative Water Content\\by fresh biomass (RWC$_f$)} & Author &
$RWC_f=\frac{AWC}{W_f}=\frac{W_f-W_d}{W_f}$
& - \\
\makecell[lt]{Relative Water Content\\by dry biomass (RWC$_d$)} & Author &
$RWC_{d}=\frac{AWC}{W_D}=\frac{W_f-W_d}{W_d}$
& - \\
\makecell[lt]{Fuel moisture content\\(FMC)} & Author &
$FMC=RWC_{d}\cdot100=\frac{W_f-W_d}{W_f} \cdot 100$
& \% \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

How one can make the equations align to the center of the cell and not the first line?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Centering in tabularx and X columns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89166/centering-in-tabularx-and-x-columns)

Comment: @TimothyTruckle: This question seem to be about horizontal centering while the OP requested vertically centered equations.

Comment: Yes, the problem is the vertical alignment... May I add an image to clarify?

Comment: @leandriis but the suggested solution should be adjustable for vertical alignment too

Comment: @TimothyTruckle Adding `\centering` to the definition of the corresponding column does not lead to vertically centered equations as you can see in the output image of theohadoulis' answer. The equations are still vertically centered with respect to the first line of a cell in the first column, not with respect to both lines of a cell in the first column.

Comment: The standard approach to vertically center contents in cells (replacing `p` columns by `m` columns (for X columns see here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/343329/134144)) does not seem to work in this specific case due to `makecells` vertical alignment option.

Comment: @leandriis there is some workaround that could allow to avoid using makecells?

Comment: @opengisapprendice: You don't have to avoid using `makecell` if you chose the correct alignent option. See my answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/408290/134144

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the following example, I have changed the alignment specifiers of the `\makecell` commands from `lt` to `lc`.

```
\documentclass[titlepage, twoside, 11pt]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2.5cm]{geometry} %doc dimensions
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell} % Tabular column heads and multilined cells
\usepackage{siunitx} % (SI) units package
\sisetup{
    range-phrase=\text{--},
    range-units=single,
}
\usepackage{tabularx} %Tabulars with adjustable-width columns

\newcolumntype{a}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{b}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l a p{7cm} l}
\toprule
Parameter & Reference & Formula & Unit\\
\midrule
\makecell[lc]{Leaf water\\content (LWC)} & Author &
$\displaystyle LWC=\frac{AWT}{A}=\frac{W_f-W_d}{A}$
& \si{\kilo\gram\per\meter\squared}\\
\makecell[lc]{Equivalent water\\thickness (EWT)} & Author &
$EWT=\frac{AWT}{\rho_w \cdot A}=\frac{W_f-W_d}{\rho_w \cdot A}$
& \si{\kilo\gram\per\meter\squared}\\
\makecell[lc]{Relative Water Content\\by fresh biomass (RWC$_f$)} & Author &
$RWC_f=\frac{AWC}{W_f}=\frac{W_f-W_d}{W_f}$
& - \\
\makecell[lc]{Relative Water Content\\by dry biomass (RWC$_d$)} & Author &
$RWC_{d}=\frac{AWC}{W_D}=\frac{W_f-W_d}{W_d}$
& - \\
\makecell[lc]{Fuel moisture content\\(FMC)} & Author &
$FMC=RWC_{d}\cdot100=\frac{W_f-W_d}{W_f} \cdot 100$
& \% \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:** To allow for better readability of the equations, the following MWE includes `\addlinespace` commands as suggested by  Bernard  in the comments.

```
\documentclass[titlepage, twoside, 11pt]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2.5cm]{geometry} %doc dimensions
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell} % Tabular column heads and multilined cells
\usepackage{siunitx} % (SI) units package
\sisetup{
    range-phrase=\text{--},
    range-units=single,
}
\usepackage{tabularx} %Tabulars with adjustable-width columns
\newcolumntype{a}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{b}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l a p{7cm} l}
\toprule
Parameter & Reference & Formula & Unit\\
\midrule
\addlinespace[10pt]
\makecell[lc]{Leaf water\\content (LWC)} & Author &
$\displaystyle LWC=\frac{AWT}{A}=\frac{W_f-W_d}{A}$
& \si{\kilo\gram\per\meter\squared}\\
\addlinespace[5pt]
\makecell[lc]{Equivalent water\\thickness (EWT)} & Author &
$EWT=\frac{AWT}{\rho_w \cdot A}=\frac{W_f-W_d}{\rho_w \cdot A}$
& \si{\kilo\gram\per\meter\squared}\\
\addlinespace[5pt]
\makecell[lc]{Relative Water Content\\by fresh biomass (RWC$_f$)} & Author &
$RWC_f=\frac{AWC}{W_f}=\frac{W_f-W_d}{W_f}$
& - \\
\addlinespace[5pt]
\makecell[lc]{Relative Water Content\\by dry biomass (RWC$_d$)} & Author &
$RWC_{d}=\frac{AWC}{W_D}=\frac{W_f-W_d}{W_d}$
& - \\
\addlinespace[5pt]
\makecell[lc]{Fuel moisture content\\(FMC)} & Author &
$FMC=RWC_{d}\cdot100=\frac{W_f-W_d}{W_f} \cdot 100$
& \% \\
\addlinespace[5pt]
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit 2:** Here is another variant that does not require the use of the `makecell` package. 
I have changed the column type of the first column to `X`, as the command `\newline` that I used to indicate line breaks inside cells can only be used in `p` or `X` type columns. Additionally, I have inserted `\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}` to allow for vertically centered alignment. I have therefore also changed the column type of the third column from `p` to `m`.

```
\documentclass[titlepage, twoside, 11pt]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
    range-phrase=\text{--},
    range-units=single,
}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X l m{7cm} l}
\toprule
Parameter & Reference & Formula & Unit\\
\midrule
\addlinespace[5pt]
Leaf water \newline content (LWC) & Author &
$\displaystyle LWC=\frac{AWT}{A}=\frac{W_f-W_d}{A}$
& \si{\kilo\gram\per\meter\squared}\\
\addlinespace[5pt]
Equivalent water \newline thickness (EWT) & Author &
$EWT=\frac{AWT}{\rho_w \cdot A}=\frac{W_f-W_d}{\rho_w \cdot A}$
& \si{\kilo\gram\per\meter\squared}\\
\addlinespace[5pt]
Relative Water Content \newline by fresh biomass (RWC$_f$) & Author &
$RWC_f=\frac{AWC}{W_f}=\frac{W_f-W_d}{W_f}$
& - \\
\addlinespace[5pt]
Relative Water Content \newline by dry biomass (RWC$_d$) & Author &
$RWC_{d}=\frac{AWC}{W_D}=\frac{W_f-W_d}{W_d}$
& - \\
\addlinespace[5pt]
Fuel moisture content \newline (FMC) & Author &
$FMC=RWC_{d}\cdot100=\frac{W_f-W_d}{W_f} \cdot 100$
& \% \\
\addlinespace[5pt]
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: In my opinion, you should add some  `\addlinespace[some value]` to separate the equations.

Comment: @Bernard: You are right. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: It's working like a charm!

Comment: @opengisapprendice I have added another variant that does not require the use of `makecell`.

Answer (score 1):

Just put  `>{\centering}p{7cm}` instead of `p{7cm}`

```
\documentclass[titlepage, twoside, 11pt]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2.5cm]{geometry} %doc dimensions
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell} % Tabular column heads and multilined cells
\usepackage{siunitx} % (SI) units package
\sisetup{
    range-phrase=\text{--},
    range-units=single,
}
\usepackage{tabularx} %Tabulars with adjustable-width columns
\newcolumntype{a}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{b}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l a >{\centering}p{7cm} l}
\toprule
Parameter & Reference & Formula & Unit\\
\midrule
\makecell[lt]{Leaf water\\content (LWC)} & Author &
$\displaystyle LWC=\frac{AWT}{A}=\frac{W_f-W_d}{A}$
& \si{\kilo\gram\per\meter\squared}\\
\makecell[lt]{Equivalent water\\thickness (EWT)} & Author &
$EWT=\frac{AWT}{\rho_w \cdot A}=\frac{W_f-W_d}{\rho_w \cdot A}$
& \si{\kilo\gram\per\meter\squared}\\
\makecell[lt]{Relative Water Content\\by fresh biomass (RWC$_f$)} & Author &
$RWC_f=\frac{AWC}{W_f}=\frac{W_f-W_d}{W_f}$
& - \\
\makecell[lt]{Relative Water Content\\by dry biomass (RWC$_d$)} & Author &
$RWC_{d}=\frac{AWC}{W_D}=\frac{W_f-W_d}{W_d}$
& - \\
\makecell[lt]{Fuel moisture content\\(FMC)} & Author &
$FMC=RWC_{d}\cdot100=\frac{W_f-W_d}{W_f} \cdot 100$
& \% \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]