# Both horizontal and vertical centering in tabularx?

Tags: tables

How to set a width of columns to be centered in vertical direction? Or in vertical and horizontal direction and the cells bellow as well?
Thank you

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\setlength\textwidth{145mm}
\setlength\textheight{247mm}
\setlength\oddsidemargin{15mm}
\setlength\evensidemargin{15mm}
\setlength\topmargin{0mm}
\setlength\headsep{0mm}
\setlength\headheight{0mm}
\let\openright=\clearpage
\begin{document}
 \begin{table}
\small
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\hsize=0.2\hsize}X
                             >{\hsize=0.25\hsize}X
                             >{\hsize=0.25\hsize}X
                             >{\hsize=0.3\hsize}X}

\Xhline{1.2pt}\noalign{\vskip 0.4ex}\Xhline{1.2pt}%                          
Název souboru&  Průměrná hodnota chyby& \makecell{Odchylka určení \\ průměrné chyby}&   \makecell{Počet středovaných \\ bodů}\\
\Xhline{1.2pt}\noalign{\vskip 0.4ex}
B & A&  C&  D\\  

\Xhline{1.2pt}  
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you like the tables :-)? Why do not use the [tag:geometry] package to set the page?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Combining `\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}` (from [Vertical centering of all columns in \tabularx environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/343329/134144)) and `\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}` (from [Centering in tabularx and X columns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89932/134144)) you can achieve the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}


\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}
 \begin{table}
\small
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\hsize=0.2\hsize}C
                             >{\hsize=0.25\hsize}C
                             >{\hsize=0.25\hsize}C
                             >{\hsize=0.3\hsize}C}

    \Xhline{1.2pt}\noalign{\vskip 0.4ex}\Xhline{1.2pt}%                          
 Název souboru&  Průměrná hodnota chyby& Odchylka určení průměrné chyby&   Počet středovaných  bodů\\
\Xhline{1.2pt}\noalign{\vskip 0.4ex}
B & A&  C&  D\\

\Xhline{1.2pt}  
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Please keep in mind that I have removed the `\makecell` cmmands as they distorted the vertical alignment. If you need to place the linebreaks manually, you can either use `\makecell[cc]{<text>}` in every column header (as suggested by [Paul Stanley in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/468318/both-horizontal-and-vertical-centering-in-tabularx/468319#comment1178253_468319)) or replace `\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}` by `\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash}X}` and use `\newline` where you want the linebreak to appear.

Comment: I ment centering like in the solution. Thank you. And please is the third column vertical centred? I mean that third and forth columns are lower

Comment: @Elisabeth: `makecell` seems to have interfered with the vertical centering of the `m` type columns. I have therefor removed it.

Comment: @leandriis Now you have eliminated the `\makecell`s, which corrects the vertical spacing, but alters the substance. Probably better to put all the headings in `\makecells` or add an optional vertical positioning argument to them?

Comment: Thank you very much. It is exactly what I expected.

Comment: @PaulStanley: What do you mean by 'alter the substance'?

Comment: @leandriis Within the `\makecell` the OP was choosing where the linebreak went. If you take the `\makecell` out, that facility is lost ... which might or might make a difference: assuming the original `\makecell` was there for a reason (and since I don't read the language concerned I can't tell) removing it may have been a significant change. But it looks as if in this case it wasn't, since OP seems happy.

Comment: @PaulStanley: You are completely right, but since the linebreaks of the third and fourth column are identical comparing the image in the question and the output of my answer (also true if one includes the width manipulations) there is clearly ne need for `makecell` at least in this particular table.

Comment: @leandriis Yes. Quite. But don't forget that a MWE may not reflect the actual final use, so maybe safer not to assume that the `\makecell` was not needed. At any rate your answer should point out that it is removed, because it is this that solves the vertical spacing problem.

Comment: @PaulStanley: I added a paragraph on the removal of the `makecell` command and two suggestions on how to achieve manual linebreaks.

Answer (score 3):

Improving a bit upon the nice solution of @leandriis, I would also remove all manual rule width manipulations and just use `booktabs` macros, they take care of widths and separation nicely. No need for `makecell` as also stated by leandriis.

If you want to break lines at certain points and used `makecell` to do that, then you can still use `\newline` for that.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}

\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}
 \begin{table}
\small
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\hsize=0.2\hsize}C
                             >{\hsize=0.25\hsize}C
                             >{\hsize=0.25\hsize}C
                             >{\hsize=0.3\hsize}C}
\toprule%                          
Název souboru & Průměrná hodnota chyby & Odchylka určení průměrné chyby & Počet středovaných bodů \\
\midrule
B             & A                      & C                              & D                       \\
\bottomrule 
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Did you test the part about `\newline` with your above example? If I add this to your code, the first line is not horizontally centered: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIJx3.png You can bypass this using `\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash}X}` instead.

Comment: `\par` can be used instead.