# Horizontal centering in tabularx cells

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, tabularx, alignment

This is my current code:

```
\newcolumntype{b}{X}
\newcolumntype{m}{>{\hsize=.5\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{s}{>{\hsize=.2\hsize}X}
\begin{table}
    \caption{Summary of the Most Common BCI Control Signals}
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{sbmmsbb}
        \hline
        \textbf{Name} & \textbf{Phenomena} & \textbf{Type} & \textbf{No. commands} & \textbf{Training} & \textbf{Advantages} & \textbf{Disadvantages} \vspace{4pt}\\
        \hline

        SSVEP & Oscillatory signals at the same frequency than a flickering visual stimuli & Exogenous & High & No & Very high transmission rates \newline No training required & Possible visual fatigue and epileptic seizures \newline No. commands limited by the standardized refreshing rate of LCD screens \newline Requires gaze control\vspace{4pt}\\
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

[image]

I want to horizontally center the row in order to get something like this:

[image]

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** Now I can center the rows using `\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}`, but I cannot modify the percentage of widths using `\newcolumntype{m}{>{\hsize=.5\hsize}X}` because it does not compile. Any solution to have both at the same time?

Comment: What you are asking for is usually referred to as "vertical centering". Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/343028/vertical-centering-of-all-columns-in-tabularx-environment.

Comment: @zetaeffe oops you are right I misread and have deleted my comment (showing how to do horizontal centering)

Comment: @zetaeffe Thank you! The redefining of '\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}' works. However, it seems that there is some incompatibility if I also use '\newcolumntype{m}{>{\hsize=.5\hsize}X}' to redefine the widths... Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Regarding your edit: Using `\newcolumntype{a}{>{\hsize=.5\hsize}X}` will work. If you include `\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}` into your document, an `m` type column (vertically centered, fixed width, automatical linebreaks)  is already defined, so using `\newcolumntype{m}` will lead to an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do *not*  use the predefined column types b and m:

```
[...]
\usepackage{tabularx}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{B}{X}
\newcolumntype{M}{>{\hsize=.5\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{s}{>{\hsize=.2\hsize}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Summary of the Most Common BCI Control Signals}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{sBMMsBB}
[...]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your computation of the coefficients is wrong: the sum of the coefficients must be equal to the total number of `X` columns. For instance, if you want to have 3 X columns, of which 1 is half as wide as the other two, you have to have as preamble

```
\begin{tabularx{>{\hsize=1.2\hsize}X>{\hsize=1.2\hsize}X>{\hsize=0.6\hsize}X}
```

Anyway, I suggest using standard X columns for the three larger ones, and c columns for the other four, combined with the `\thead` command from `makecell`, which allows for line breaks and a common formatting of cells:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe, hmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx, ragged2e, caption, makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\RaggedRight}m{#1}}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
    \caption{Summary of the Most Common BCI Control Signals}
    \centering\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{cXcccXX}
        \hline
        \thead{Name} & \thead{Phenomena} & \thead{Type} & \thead{No. \\commands} & \thead{Training} & \thead{Advantages} & \thead{Disadvantages} \\
        \hline
        SSVEP & Oscillatory signals at the same frequency than a flickering visual stimuli & Exogenous & High & No & Very high transmission rates \newline No training required & Possible visual fatigue and epileptic seizures \newline No. commands limited by the standardized refreshing rate of LCD screens \newline Requires gaze control\vspace{4pt}\\
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: With `ragged2e` you do not need `\arraybackslash`

Comment: I didn't know that. Thanks for the information!